# Why is my SwiftUI List row not always updating internally

Tags: reactive-programming, swiftui, swiftui-list

I have a list of reminders grouped into sections by completion and date. With data coming from an ObservedObject DataStore called global. I pass a realmBinding to the cell. The cell can update this binding and it will trigger the data store to update.

```
List {
    // Past Due
    if self.global.pastDueReminders.count > 0 {
        Section(header: SectionHeader {}){
            ForEach(self.global.pastDueReminders) { reminder in
                NavigationLink(destination: ReminderDetail( reminder: reminder.realmBinding())) {
                    GeneralReminderCell(reminder: reminder.realmBinding())
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Completed
    if self.global.completeReminders.count > 0 {
        // Same as PastDue but for Completed
    }
}
```

The cell looks something like:

```
struct GeneralReminderCell: View {
    @Binding var reminder:Reminder

    var body: some View {
        HStack(alignment:.top, spacing: 10) {
            Image(systemName: reminder.completed ? "checkmark.circle.fill" : "circle")
                .onTapGesture(perform:{ self.reminder.completed = !self.reminder.completed })
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 2) {
                Text("Follow up with \(reminder.client.fullName)").fontWeight(.semibold)
                if reminder.title.count > 0 {
                    Text(reminder.title)
                }

                Text(reminder.date.formatted()).foregroundColor(.gray)
            }
        }.padding(.vertical, 10)
    }
}
```

When tapping on an image it toggles the reminder completion state and its position changes in the List view. The image that was tapped should changed to a filled in check when completed.
This behaviour almost always happens as expected, but sometimes the checked image will get out of sync with the completed state of reminder. I've look at this for quite some time and have not made much headway. Why is the checked image not always matching the state of the data?

Comment: I think this could have something to do with the backing UITableView and how it reuses cell rows.

Comment: The issue is rather in states than in cells. There is no view model provided. What in your code triggers update for List? Where this cell `reminder` is bound to?

Comment: @Asperi what are you talking about? I don’t think you read my post properly. I clearly state that that data is coming from an observed data store. I also clearly said that it works nearly perfect most of the time. It wouldn’t work at all if there was no view model. What you are saying makes no sense. My backing data setup is a little much to ad to this post. The realmBinding updates a realm store which triggers the data store to change. I also say in my post that the cells reorder fine just that sometimes an image in one of cells doesn’t reflect the data properly.

Comment: Did you get this one figured out?

Answer (score 0):

Even though this is a very old question, I may have been working on what appears to be this same problem. In my case, my App is running on macOS.  At first, the problem also seemed to be very intermittent and had been difficult to reproduce consistently.

I also have a `View` with a `ForEach` supplying rows to a `List`.  My row's `View` contains an `@State` for an Optional `Image` that gets updated several different ways via actions performed by that same row `View` (e.g. Continuity Camera, file picker or drag & drop).  The issue is that sometimes the new `Image` is shown and sometimes it is not shown.  Using `Self._printChanges()` I am able to see that the `@State` is changing and the row's body it is being redrawn, however, the rendered `View` does not change.  The only pattern that I am able to observe is that this issue only seems to occur with the last row in the `List`.  Based on the success of my workaround below, it seems to confirm that there is an issue with the way SwiftUI's `List` reuses table cells.

My solution/workaround is to replace:

```
List {
    ForEach {
    }
}
```

With:

```
ScrollView {
    LazyVStack {
        ForEach {
        }
    }
}
```