# SwiftUI Row in Grouped List Not Updating Properly

Tags: swiftui-list, swiftui

[image: Odd SwiftUI]

I've run into an issue where the user updates an item in one section which causes it to be filtered and moved into another section.  When that happens, the content of the row view doesn't always get updated.  As seen in the image, when the item stays in the same section, it updates every times and when it moves it's only updated every other time (though that doesn't always seem to be the case).  It behaves as if the row view is being reused and the object provided to it isn't updated.  I'm wondering if anyone has run into this and knows what to do.

Here's the code on how to recreate this view.

In `SceneDelegate.swift`:

```
let contentView = ContentView().environmentObject(ItemStore())


if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
  let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
  window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: contentView)
  self.window = window
  window.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```

Then in `ContentView.swift`:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
  @EnvironmentObject var itemStore: ItemStore

  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      List {
          Section(header: Text("Even")) {
              ForEach(itemStore.itemsEven) { item in
                  ItemRowView(item: item) {
                      self.itemStore.increment(item: item)
                  }
              }
          }
          Section(header: Text("Odd")) {
              ForEach(itemStore.itemsOdd) { item in
                  ItemRowView(item: item) {
                      self.itemStore.increment(item: item)
                  }
              }
          }
          Section(header: Text("All")) {
              ForEach(itemStore.itemsAll) { item in
                  ItemRowView(item: item) {
                      self.itemStore.increment(item: item)
                  }
              }
          }
      }
      .listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
      .navigationBarTitle("Items")
  }
 }
}

struct ItemRowView: View {
  var item: Item
  var onTap: () -> Void
  var body: some View {
    HStack {
        Text(item.name)
        Spacer()
        Button(action: onTap) {
            Text("\(item.count)")
        }
    }
  }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    ContentView().environmentObject(ItemStore())
  }
}

struct Item: Identifiable {
  var id: String
  var name: String
  var count: Int

  var isEven: Bool {
    count % 2 == 0
  }
}

class ItemStore: ObservableObject {
  @Published var itemsEven: [Item]
  @Published var itemsOdd: [Item]
  @Published var itemsAll: [Item]

  init() {
    let even = [
        Item(id: "0", name: "Star Wars", count: 0),
    ]
    let odd: [Item] = []
    itemsEven = even
    itemsOdd = odd
    itemsAll = even + odd
  }

  func increment(item: Item) {
    printItems(title: "START")
    var allItems = itemsAll
    let index = allItems.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == item.id })!
    let storedItem = allItems[index] // avoid captured value
    allItems[index].count = storedItem.count + 1

    print("DURING \(allItems) \(allItems[index].count) \(item.count + 1)")

    allItems.sort { $0.count < $1.count }

    itemsEven = []
    itemsOdd = []

    allItems.forEach { item in
        if item.isEven {
            itemsEven.append(item)
        } else {
            itemsOdd.append(item)
        }
    }

    itemsAll = allItems

    printItems(title: "END")
  }

  func printItems(title: String) {
    print("\(title) ------------")
    print("All \(itemsAll)")
    print("Even \(itemsEven)")
    print("Odd \(itemsOdd)")
    print("------------------")
  }
}
```

It's a possible duplicate of [Why is my SwiftUI List row not always updating internally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59186046/why-is-my-swiftui-list-row-not-always-updating-internally)

Oh, and it's kind of odd of the margin's on the left shift on first tap.

Comment: If you don't care about the animation, you can add .id() on the `List`

Comment: Ah, but I like the animation!

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? No amount of overriding Hashable, Equatable, Identifiable seems to fix the issue for me. The IDs come from elsewhere so I can’t just pick a new ID, and I want the animation.

Comment: @MrRogers - This very well could be a duplicate of the question that you referenced. I have responded to that question with an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71742060/899918

Answer (score 1):

It is because `Item.id` is not changed, so `List` tracks the item as same item (either due to issue or by design - unknown), so the following added line fixes the update (because item is interpreted as new).

```
allItems[index].count = storedItem.count + 1
allItems[index].id = UUID().uuidString // !! modified value, so update ID
```

Of course this approach not always will be appropriate, but for clarification purpose I assume it would be helpful to provide it for consideration.

Comment: That would work, but it seems like a workaround that I really want to avoid.  Ultimately, I would hope that I wouldn't need to change the identifier for an object.  The reason why I ran into this is that I'm getting objects from a server and that they're sorted into various lists based off of their properties (which can change each time they're fetched).  I really don't want to give them a different identifier simply so the lists can be updated correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The formal answer is the formal answer is missing `Hashable`

```
    struct Item: Identifiable, Hashable {
     var id: String
     var name: String
    var count: Int

      var isEven: Bool {
    count % 2 == 0
   }
  }
```

So you can use list with an `id` way.

```
    Section(header: Text("Odd")) {
        ForEach(itemStore.itemsOdd, id:\.self) { item in
                     ItemRowView(item: item ,onTap: {

                        self.updateItems(item)
                     })
                 }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears that this is fixed in iOS 14 (just tried in beta 3 and it updated properly after changing sections). Not ideal for iOS 13 development—seems our options there are either deal with it or have no nice changing-sections animation—but at least it will work in iOS 14.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to make Item an ObservableObject and @Publish each value so updates will be updated in place.  Using structs they are assumed to be immutable.

Comment: Mind elaborating in this answer? I think that would be nice for the community to follow with an example.